# Pdf.js text overlay only adds to canvas. How to log it to console?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, canvas, pdf.js

Today I found [this fantastic code example](http://git.macropus.org/2011/11/pdftotext/example/) on how to extract text from a pdf file using pdf.js. The functionality is perfect, but the script itself has more code than what's really needed to call the pdf.js library and is rather messy. An example of this is having an un-needed(?) ajax call to another page. Due to this reason, I decided to clean up this code so I, and others, can use it in future projects.

I've spent all day cleaning up this code and making it work with the html5 file api, but there is one slight issue with my re-write...

For the life of me I can't figure out how to log the output pdf page text to the browser console after looping over each text layer within a PDF page. The text will add to the page DOM, but it's inside a canvas with it's original font, which is no good. I want to achieve the same functionality as the existing script - that is adding text to a div so it looks like plaintext. I don't want to have the canvas html, or the original font appended to the text.

The problem lies here in [filedrag.js](https://github.com/jjmpsp/html5pdf/blob/master/filedrag.js):

```
page.startRendering(context, function(){
    if (++self.complete == total){            
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            var layers = [];
            var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".textLayer > div");
            for (var j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++){
                layers.push(nodes[j].textContent + "\n");
            }
            console.log("testing logging");
            console.log(layers.join("\n").replace(/\s+/g, " "));
        }, 1000);
    }
}, textLayer);
```

As you can see, I have added a debug line to the code (on line 9 above):

```
console.log("testing logging");
```

But if you try run my version of the script and uploading the pdf file supplied, no data will get outputted to the browser console, but the text will be appended to the DOM as a parent of a canvas element. Grr!

Why isn't the text being outputted to the browser console? I have a feeling this is some sort of threading problem, but I'm really not experienced enough with writing Javascript to be able to tell. The original code sends variables through `window` by using an iframe, but I find this really ugly and I'd much prefer to use my version of the code as it's neater and more flexible to extend.

[I have posted this project to github](https://github.com/jjmpsp/html5pdf/), as it requires extra dependencies which meant that I couldn't post it up on jsfiddle etc... This is my first time using github, so I hope the repo is accessible for everyone.

If anyone can help me out here, I would really appreciate it. Any fix suggestions would be nice. I'm not expecting someone to just go ahead and fix this code for me, I'd just love some pointers as to how I can fix this.

Cheers.

Comment: I went through the files that added in git. Can you tell me where you are inputting the PDF itself ?

Comment: Never mind, i understand now that the pdf is supposed to be inputted by the user

Comment: A pdf needs to be dragged onto the "filedrag" div, or browsed for.

Comment: Any ideas? Nobody is voting on this question, so hardly anyone is seeing it. On a side note, this simple problem is driving me crazy haha.

Comment: I can't get the pdf.js from anywhere. Can you host the file from some repo ? Then probably i will be able to refer it easily. I am trying to fiddle it, but the fiddle does not take the raw version of the pdf.js you posted in git . Tried for almost 2 hrs to get the pdf.js (: No luck

Comment: Have you tried linking to this? http://git.macropus.org/2011/11/pdftotext/pdf.js I know the file is pretty large for a Javascript.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35481/discussion-between-the-dark-knight-and-joel-murphy)